# Mocking a method that has a parameter returns an empty list

Tags: python, flask, mocking

I have a function that get's a list of users from a local ldap.
I want to mock this function so i can check if the return json equals expected json.
If i don't mock it the test passes
If i mock it i get an empty list and the test fails

My func:

```
@app.route('/users', methods=['GET'])
def user_list():
    list_1 = []
    users = ldap.get_group_members('ship_crew')

    for user in users:
        list_1.append(str(user).split(",")[0].split("=")[1])
    return jsonify(list_1)
```

this func returns a list of strings

My unittest:

```
@patch('dev_maintenance.user_list.ldap.get_group_members')
    def test_content_type(self, get_group_members):

        get_group_members.return_value
        test_client = app.test_client()
        valid_credentials = base64.b64encode(b'hermes:hermes').decode('utf-8')
        response = test_client.get('/users', follow_redirects=True, content_type='application/json',  headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + valid_credentials})
        expected_json = ["Philip J. Fry", "Turanga Leela","Bender Bending Rodr\\xc3\\xadguez"]

        assert response.get_json() == expected_json
```

The Error:

```
>       assert response.get_json() == expected_json
E       AssertionError: assert [] == ['Philip J. Fry', 'Turanga L...Bending Rodr\\xc3\\xadguez']
E         Right contains more items, first extra item: 'Philip J. Fry'
E         Full diff:
E         - []
E         + ['Philip J. Fry', 'Turanga Leela', 'Bender Bending Rodr\\xc3\\xadguez']
```

The mock makes the response.get_json() empty, don't know why.
Do i need to pass the ('ship_crew') parameter somewhere?

Comment: `ldap` is not an attribute of `user_list`; it's (likely) a global attribute of `dev_maintenance` (assuming that's the module where `user_list` is defined).

Comment: You also haven't actually assigned anything to `get_group_members.return_value`.

Comment: the ldap has to be there, otherwise it does not recognise the function. I did add the return value as the full string ```"cn=Philip J. Fry,ou=people,dc=planetexpress,dc=com", \
                                         "cn=Turanga Leela,ou=people,dc=planetexpress,dc=com", \
                                         "cn=Bender Bending Rodr\u00edguez,ou=people,dc=planetexpress,dc=com"``` and if i compare it with the expect string, as the full string it works, but what i expect is the parsed one, i still didn't figure it out

Comment: i pass the full list as return result, when the i get the response i should had my parsed list no? but i didn't get it. If i do this way i get this error:                       ```E       AssertionError: assert ['cn=Philip J...press,dc=com'] == ('Philip J. Fr...xc3\\xadguez')
E         At index 0 diff: 'cn=Philip J. Fry,ou=people,dc=planetexpress,dc=com' != 'Philip J. Fry'
E         Use -v to get the full diff```

Answer (score 0):

I could find the solution, needed to pass a token and a return value in the mocked method:

```
    def test_content_type_json_protected(self, get_group_members):

        with app.test_request_context():
            access_token = create_access_token('hermes')


        get_group_members.return_value = "cn=Philip J. Fry,ou=people,dc=planetexpress,dc=com", \
                                         "cn=Turanga Leela,ou=people,dc=planetexpress,dc=com", \
                                         "cn=Bender Bending Rodr\u00edguez,ou=people,dc=planetexpress,dc=com"
        test_client = app.test_client()
        valid_credentials = {'Authorization': 'Bearer {}'.format(access_token)}
        response = test_client.get('/users', follow_redirects=True, content_type='application/json',headers=valid_credentials)
        expected_json = ["Philip J. Fry", "Turanga Leela", "Bender Bending Rodr\u00edguez"]

        assert response.get_json() == expected_json
```